# WPF : How to style the initial state of a radiobutton group?

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, styles

I just want to give an initial style to my radiobutton group, before one of the radiobuttons is checked or unchecked:

```
<Style x:Key="RadioButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}">
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In this example, all my radiobuttons are unfortunately green, whereas I would like them to be red until the user clicks on one of them (at this point, the clicked button turns blue, and the others turn green).

How can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the **isChecked** property for each RadioButton. Like this

```
   <RadioButton GroupName="players" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Name="hvP1" IsChecked="True"/>
   <RadioButton GroupName="players" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" Name="hvP2" IsChecked="False"/>
   ...
```